# IOS: class comunication

Tags: ios, xcode, class, uiviewcontroller

I have this problem:

I have a FirstViewController and its xib;
inside this xib there is a view and its class is PaintingView (a class from glpaint, it's not a view controller but it's for a view).

Then in firstviewcontroller I import "PaintingView.h", but if I call a method of PantingView it don't work

in firstViewcontroller I do, in viewdidload:

```
paintingView = [[PaintingView alloc]init];
```

but inside an IBAction I do:

```
[paintingView method1];
```

(where method1 is in PaintingView), it don't work, why???
thanks

Comment: "it didn't work" just doesn't give enough information.  Are you sure your "paintingView" isn't nil by the time you call your method?

Comment: yes I verify it I do if (paintingView == nil) NSLog(@"paintingview nil"); but it don't happen

Answer (score 1):

So:

> inside this xib there is a view and its class is PaintingView

If it's `UIView` sub-class and it's inside of your Xib, I am assuming you are then using an iBOutlet to actually access it. But then you do:

```
paintingView = [[PaintingView alloc]init];
```

My question is why? You already have it instantiated in the Xib.

Comment: ok, but if I don't write paintingView = [[PaintingView alloc]init];
it's the same...it don't work

Comment: Ok, can you edit the PaintingView class? **If yes**, can you add a new method with a NSLog on it, just to see if it's called. **If no**, create a category and test if the method is called.

Comment: I add a method in PaintingView - (void) erase and inside it I write NSLog(@"erase"); so in FirstViewController I create an IBAction and inside I put [paintingView erase] and it don't work

Comment: Well, I rest my case then (you know it shouldn't be, right?).

Comment: Now, I'm able to print a nslog inside a method of PaintingView but it do only it, and other instryction inside method not run

Comment: Well, if you are able to communicate with the PaintingView and you are at least able to use an `NSLog`I assume the other instruction is wrong.

Comment: I really don't understand...nslog work and other instruction that I test with IbAction inside PaintingView (and work fine inside it) don't work, it's incredible

Comment: example I try to do "self.alpha= 0;" and it don't work but if I do in the same method NSLog(@"example"); I see it in console...

Comment: no it's not the problem...because if I use an UIButton inside PaintingView with an IBaction inside it and inside this IBAction I write self.alpha = 0; it work fine...

Comment: Ok. Glad I could help somehow.